# Error dialog in MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I use MVVM light toolkit in WPF application and I get data from external source. My MainViewModel c'tor look like that:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        try
        {
            GetData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //here i want to show error dialog
        }
    }
```

I cannot send message (like it done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)) to view because ModelView is created before View so there is nobody that can receive message and show dialog. What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should only throw exceptions from the constructor if initialization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639/when-is-it-right-for-a-constructor-to-throw-an-exception). In this case you can start the retrieval of the data when the view is loaded. You can invoke a commmand of the VM from the loaded event with the use of [Attached Command Behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the technique in the post you linked, I'd do something like this:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        GetData();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new DialogMessage(this, e.Message, MessageBoxCallback) { Caption = "Error!" });
    }
}

private void MessageBoxCallback(MessageBoxResult result)
{
    // Stuff that happens after dialog is closed
}


public class View1 : UserControl
{
    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(this, DialogMessageReceived);
    }

    private void DialogMessageReceived(DialogMessage msg)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(msg.Content, msg.Caption, msg.Button, msg.Icon, msg.DefaultResult, msg.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specifically states that the View has not been created yet.