# What is the difference between "throws Exception" and "throws IOException"

Tags: java, exception

What is the difference between `throws Exception` and `throws IOException`?

Either of them works. So, what's the major difference in between them? What if one of them had not existed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use IOexception instead of Exception when catching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644559/why-use-ioexception-instead-of-exception-when-catching)

Comment: because handling the concrete problem is much better then handling all the problems at once. Exception is parent of all Exceptions, including RunTime onces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really about the basics of Java exception mechanism, but, strangely, I couldn't find an exact duplicate on StackOverflow...

---

These declarations tell the compiler (and the programmers) which *type(s) of exceptions* may be thrown by a method.

```
throws Exception
```

means that a method may throw any `Exception` (either an `Exception` instance directly, or any subtype of `Exception`, including `IOException`).

```
throws IOException
```

tells that a method may throw an `IOException`, but not, for example, `SQLException`.

It is usually a good practice to declare *specific* exceptions, e.g. `throws IOException, ParseException`, instead of just writing `throws Exception`.