# Throw exception inside catch clause

Tags: java, exception

I have two snippet of code :

```
class PreciseRethrow {
public static void main(String[] str) {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ife) {
        System.out.println(ife);
    }
}

static private void foo() throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt("ten");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

and :

```
class PreciseRethrow {
public static void main(String[] str) {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ife) {
        System.out.println(ife);
    }
}

static private void foo() throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt("ten");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
}
```

In second case I got compile error "Unhandled exception type Exception" when I throw new Exception () in catch clause. Can You explain me Why in first case everything is ok but in second i get compile error ? In both case I throw Exception but in second case i create new instance of exception (this in only difference beetwen this two examples). Thanks for help.

Comment: @prash: Did you forget to actually vote?

Comment: Yes!  Infact I did from mobile. And request not completed.  3g was veryslow. Did it now. Thanks. @Keppil

Answer (score 7):

First of all: **your first example does not compile with Java 6 either**. It *will* however compile with Java 7 due to new features in exception handling.

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow) for more information. Basically, starting with Java 7, the compiler can analyze exceptions thrown form a `try` block more precisely; and even if you catch a superclass of one or more thrown exceptions and rethrow it "as is" (ie, without a cast), the compiler will not complain. Java 6 and earlier, however, *will* complain.

In your second example however you rethrow a **new** instance of `Exception`. And indeed, this does not match the signature.

All in all, it means that with Java 7, you can do that, but not with Java 6:

```
public void someMethod()
    throws MyException
{
    try {
        throw new MyException();
    } catch (Exception e) { // Note: Exception, not MyException
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Java 6 only sees that the catch parameter is of type `Exception`; and for Java 6, this does not match the method signature --> compile error.

Java 7 sees that the try block can only throw `MyException`. The method signature therefore matches --> no compile error.

But don't do this ;) It is rather confusing...

Comment: Well explained especially when concluded

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the compiler can see that the only checked exception that can be rethrown in the first example is a `NumberFormatException`. (You are not creating any new exceptions.) Therefore it is happy with the `throws NumberFormatException {` declaration in the header.

In the second example however, you are explicitly throwing a checked exception that is not declared in the header, so predictably you get a compiler error.

Comment: I understood this only after reading @fge. Difference between java6 and java7. But good

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you are re-throwing the `NumberFormatException` that could possibly come up. In the second code snippet, you are throwing just general `Exception`, which is not `NumberFormatException`, as the method has declared.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to throw an Exception, however you declare that you will throw a `NumberFormatException`, which is a subtype of `Exception`. All `NumberFormatException`s are `Exception`s, however not all `Exception`s are `NumberFormatException`, so it is not allowed. In the first example however, although you are catching an `Exception`, the compiler and IDE know that it will only ever be a `NumberFormatException`, which is safe.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can determine in the case of `throw e`, that it can only be a checked exception of type `NumberFormatException` which is already declared in the throws clause.

In the latter case you're trying to throw the checked `Exception` which needs to be declared in the throws clause or caught.

Answer (score 0):

Here ,You are throwing new Exception() from catch block but you have mentioned your method foo() can throw only NumberFormatException() which is lower in hierarchy

```
   static private void foo() throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt("ten");
   } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Both the case compile time error comes.Because you are try to throw a checked exception named Exception.
You have to do one of two things:

use try construct in catch block
OR
 add Exception in throws clause of foo()