# How to handle a runtime error with throws

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception, throws

In the following code snippet, there are cases where the processes cannot handle `NullPointerException` and `IllegalStateException`. Namely in the case where I have the input values `val=-4` or `val=-2`.

I read that adding `throws` after methods' signatures would help. But the code still aborts if I pass the mentioned values over.

```
public class Test extends Throwable{
    public static void processA(int val ) throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException{
        try{
            System.out.println("1");
            processB(val);
        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        System.out.println("3");
    }
    public static void processB(int val) throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException{
        try{
            System.out.println("4");
            processC(val);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("5");
            processC(val+4);
        }finally{
            System.out.println("6");
        }
        System.out.println("7");
    }
    public  static void processC(int val)throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException, ArithmeticException{
        System.out.println("8");
        if(val<1) throw new NullPointerException();
        if(val==1) throw new ArithmeticException();
        if(val>1) throw new IllegalStateException();
        System.out.println("9");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         processA(1); //processA(-2) or processA(-4)
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do if, say, val < 1?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code will only finish properly if you use "1" as parameter

Comment: Anyway, you could do some reading on RuntimeExceptions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996407/java-throws-runtimeexception

Comment: On a old slide I found this example, where one has to explain how the flow through the code looks like. There was also a note to use `throw NullPointerException, IllegalStateException' after the signature of the method. But why should I use it? I can understand, that a correct version would use multiple catch-blocks for handeling all exceptions.

Comment: @Susliks - *"But why should I use it?"* -- This will indicate that the caller will need to handle the exception thrown by that method. Now the caller can handle it via a `try-catch` block or it can re-throw the exception to *its* caller. The compiler would also give you an error saying that the exception should be handled but this would happen only for *checked* exceptions. The ones you are throwing are *unchecked* exceptions. Which means in your case you can pretty much ignore them from the method declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It breaks because you are not handling the scenario when a `NullPointerException` or `IllegalStateException` is thrown to `processA(...)`. You only handle an *ArithmeticException*.

Add the following to your code, thereby if any of the three exceptions are thrown, it is handled by method `processA`.

```
public static void processA(int val) throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException {
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        processB(val);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("11");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("12");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        System.out.println("13");
    }
    System.out.println("3");
}
```

If you want the caller to handle them then you need to do the same from the *caller* method. For eg :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        processA(12);
    } catch (ArithmeticException | NullPointerException | IllegalStateException e) {
        // do something here
    } 
}
```

*To answer your question in the comments: "But why should I use it?"*

This will indicate that the caller will need to handle the exception thrown by that method. Now the caller can handle it via a `try-catch` block or it can re-throw the exception to *its* caller. The compiler would also give you an error saying that the exception should be handled but this would happen only for *checked* exceptions. The ones you are throwing are *unchecked* exceptions. Which means in your case you can pretty much ignore them from the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you also consider using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` in order to make sure you properly handle exceptions which were not properly caught.

Missing out on exception handling is a very common occurrence and can be easily avoided using this API.

References:

- [How to catch an exception from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread)
- [Oracle official API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)
- [UncaughtExceptionHandler as a best practice](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229)