# Reason that Java code dealing with Arrays not requiring try-catch for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception, primitive-types

I would like to inquire the reason (rule in Java's design) that makes dealing with Arrays such as:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println(args[2]);
}
```

not requiring a try and catch for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Are there some exceptions that are implicitly always method-`throws` assigned by `javac` or is javac simply inconsistent here?

Any answer would be appreciated to provide some references to he design specs/docu about this behaviour.

Comment: You can find additional information about checked and uncheck exceptions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540613/please-explain-runtimeexception-in-java-and-where-it-should-be-used

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you would be forced to explicitly catch all possible NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: The key point to me is there: "Use checked exceptions for conditions from which the caller can reasonably be expected to recover" vs. "Use runtime exceptions to indicate programming errors.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a sub-class of `RuntimeException`, which makes it an unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exception don't need to be caught, and don't need to be declared in a throws clause.

This is stated in the Javadoc of `RuntimeException`:

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

Answer (score 0):

That has been discussed in JLS # 10.4. Array Access

> All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown (§15.10.4).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4