# Should I nest try...except blocks?

Tags: python, try-catch

I want to store some data in a web. I want to do two operations: the first is to open a URL, the second is to store data,  with both of them in `try...except` blocks.

I'd like to know if nesting `try...except` is good or not, and why.

Solution one:

```
try:
    # open url
    # store data
except:
    # url doesn't exist
    # cannot store
```

Solution two:

```
try:
    # open url
    try:
        # store data
    except:
        # cannot store
except:
    # cannot open url
```

Comment: Is it any difference for error handling for first and second operations?

Comment: Also consider if `try..except..else`[1] would be appropriate so as to not accidentally catch exceptions that you didn't mean to trap. [1]http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: You may have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799758/are-nested-try-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea).

Comment: @dbf thegrinner help me changed thed code,so they are different now

Answer (score 1):

As naiquevin suggested, it might be useful to catch exactly what you intend to:

```
try:
    openURL()
except URLError:
    print "cannot open URL"
else:
    try:
        saveData()
    except IOError:
        print "cannot save data"
```

Comment: You misspelt "except".

Comment: @deadly And I doubled "exactly".

Comment: You were just being precise. :D