# Is there a throws keyword in C# like in Java?

Tags: c#, java, exception, throw, throws

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use Java-style throws keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465465/how-to-use-java-style-throws-keyword-in-c)

i have a function where an exception occurs
say for example

```
private void functionName() throws Exception
{
   // some code that might throw an exception
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

No, because there are no checked exceptions in C#

If you are trying to document exceptions that are thrown, use the standard xml documentation

```
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Why it's thrown.</exception>
```

Comment: I noticed that the text I write in the exception element is not shown next to the exception in the Intellisense popup for the method. Do you know where it shows up?

Answer (score 19):

No. There is no such construct in c#. But you can add the comment to your method like this 
`/// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>`
and it will be visible in IntelliSense

Comment: i am talking about throws keyword

Comment: throw keyword is used to throw exception itself like 
"throw new Exception()". And exception is raised

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there isn't, and it can be a pain.  The remedy is to be more careful with the exceptions that your code throws and how you handle errors.