# Throwing an exception in c#

Tags: c#, java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use Java-style throws keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465465/how-to-use-java-style-throws-keyword-in-c)

I am on a work placement at the moment, and doing c#. I am 1 year away from finishing uni where we have predominantly been taught Java.

If I was going to throw a checked exception in Java I would use:

```
public void saveToFile(String fileName) throws IOException
```

Is there similar syntax in C# for doing this but for my own custom exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noop. You just have to `catch` and `throw`. Or wrap it into a new exception and `throw`.

```
public void saveToFile(string fileName)
{  
    try
    {
        // your code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
        //or: throw new Exception("Whoops", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, no. Don't ever do `throw ex`. Just `throw;` is sufficient. If you rethrow `ex`, you lose the stack trace.

Comment: @Mike, good point! Changed the code.

Answer (score 4):

In c#, you don't declare the exception that a function may throw. You declare a function regularely:

```
public void saveToFile( string fileName ) {
    ....
}
```

Throwing an exception is very easy. There are many predefined exception (such as System.IO.IOException), which you can throw:

```
using System.IO

...

public void saveToFile(* string fileName ) {

    ...
    throw new IOException( )
}
```

If you want to throw a custom exception, you have to declare it, and make sure it derives from System.Exception class. You exception class can have any constructor, property or member that you want. e.g.

```
public class MyException :Exception
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public MyException(int c) { code = c; }
}
```

Then, in your code you'll simply throw an instance of it:

```
...
throw new MyException( 666 );
```

Comment: and possibly override ToString in the exception class ;)