# How can I report exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#, throws

I have this code in `Java`, that I used to report exceptions (throws `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`, `ClassNotFoundException`).

Example:

```
private void functionName() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{}
```

I need to do this in `C#`, how can I do that?

Comment: You can't.  C# doesn't support declaring checked exceptions, or any type of exceptions for that matter, in the method signature.  Best you can do is add some documentation that declares which exceptions are expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are checked exceptions in Java/C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371686/what-are-checked-exceptions-in-java-c)

Comment: To add onto what @sstan said, you can use the `/// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException">...</exception>` tag, described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1htk11d.aspx). This is just documentation, though, and not checked exceptions.

Comment: Here's an article on why the designers of C# choose not to include checked exceptions into the language: http://web.archive.org/web/20070314071137/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336812.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Java-style throws keyword in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465465/how-to-use-java-style-throws-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. In C#, you can't directly use a `throws` statement, because there isn´t. You may want to use this code:

```
    private void functionName(){ throw new IOException();}
```

This throws an IOException. As IOException being a class, you need to create a new one, with `new` statement.