# Detecting if a CompletableFuture is cancelled from within task

Tags: java

I am struggling to figure out why the task is not cancelling when using `CompletableFuture#cancel`. Essentially, I am creating an asynchronous task, which does it's thing (time consuming), after it finishes a single "part" it checks the original future to see if it was `ComplateableFuture#isCancelled`.

Here's the commit (ignore some useless code) - the invocation is in the test. The archive handler checks the cancelled state.
https://github.com/Axieum/Compressum/commit/ccc1edcbac8df684e10339f4106a7b1817af9397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interrupt underlying execution of CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013831/how-to-interrupt-underlying-execution-of-completablefuture)

Comment: Do you ever call your `Compressum.cancel()` method?

Comment: No, that was just there as a test. Will probably resort to that. Just wanted to see if could get it working with futures built-in cancelling.