# How to wrap a supplier with a java future that returns a value on timeout but keeps running in the background (with option to cancel)

Tags: java, future, completable-future

As an example, I have a supplier that might take time to run:

```
Supplier<Integer> numLoader = sneaky(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("5 Calculated!");
    return 5;
});
```

* `sneaky` is just a utility to convert to runtime exception.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Future<Integer> future = createFutureValueOnTimeout(-1, numLoader);
// numLoader takes 10 seconds to complete so -1 is returned.
int num = future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
if (resourcesAreLow()) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
doSomethingWithTheValue(num);
```

I also have a partial implementation for `createFutureValueOnTimeout`:

```
private static <V> Future<V> createFutureValueOnTimeout(V v, Supplier<V> supplier) {
    CompletableFuture<V> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier);
    return new FutureDecorator<V>(completableFuture) {
        @Override
        public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return completableFuture.completeOnTimeout(v, timeout, unit).get();
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that when calling `cancel`, the `sleep` isn't interrupted.

1. **How can I get the cancel to work?**
2. **Is there an easier way to return a value on timeout?**

Complete test:

```
public class TimeoutTest {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void testTimeout() {
        int loadTimeMillis = 10000;
        Supplier<Integer> numLoader = () -> {
            try {
                // Simulate long operation
                Thread.sleep(loadTimeMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted! message: " + e.getMessage());
                throw Lombok.sneakyThrow(e);
            }
            System.out.println("5 Calculated!");
            return 5;
        };

        Future<Integer> future = createFutureValueOnTimeout(-1, numLoader);
        
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // numLoader takes 10 seconds to complete so -1 is returned.
        int num = future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out.println("Got: num: " + num + ". time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        if (resourcesAreLow()) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        // Don't stop the test. Give time for the cancel to kick in.
        Thread.sleep(loadTimeMillis);
        System.out.println("Finished. Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    private boolean resourcesAreLow() {
        return true;
    }

    private static <V> Future<V> createFutureValueOnTimeout(V v, Supplier<V> supplier) {
        CompletableFuture<V> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier);
        return new FutureDecorator<V>(completableFuture) {
            @Override
            public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                return completableFuture.completeOnTimeout(v, timeout, unit).get();
            }
        };
    }

    private static class FutureDecorator<V> implements Future<V> {
        private final Future<V> inner;

        private FutureDecorator(Future<V> inner) {this.inner = inner;}

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            return inner.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return inner.isCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            return inner.isDone();
        }

        @Override
        public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return inner.get();
        }

        @Override
        public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            return inner.get(timeout, unit);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: (**Notice the lack of the `Interrupted!` message**)

```
Got: num: -1. time: 1007
5 Calculated!
Finished. Time: 11021
```

Comment: The problem seems strangely simple... At least part of the answer is in the docs of `cancel`: ***mayInterruptIfRunning** this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.*

Comment: And yet another part of the answer is that you can't count on `cancel` to stop the actual work done in the supplier; [seems you'll have to do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013831/how-to-interrupt-underlying-execution-of-completablefuture). I think the solution will be complete if you combine `completeOnTimeout` and something like `whenComplete` on its resulting CompletableFutre, making that `whenComplete` stop the actual work (in cases where `mayInterruptIfRunning == true`, of course)

Comment: Why do you focus on adding an unsupported feature to `CompletableFuture`? Just use `Future<Integer> future = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> { Thread.sleep(10000); System.out.println("5 Calculated!"); return 5; });` It uses the same pool as `CompletableFuture` uses (by default) but doesn’t require `sneaky` and it provides a future supporting cancelation with interruption. Good old Java 5 concurrency API…

Comment: @Holger, I'm trying to get some default value on timeout. CompletableFuture can help do that. Can't see how I can do it with a "regular" future.

Comment: I don’t see how “CompletableFuture can help do that”. In your examples, all relevant variables are literally declared as `Future<Integer>`. You already have a wrapper implementing `Future`, so all you need to do, is to allow this wrapper to be completed with the default values when canceling the wrapped future, assuming that you wrap a future which does support cancelation.

Comment: @Holger, `CompletableFuture` helps by using it's api: `completableFuture.completeOnTimeout(v, timeout, unit)`. I don't need to handle the timeout myself.

Comment: You want to cancel the original job on timeout and `completeOnTimeout` doesn’t do that. So no, it does not help. Catching the `TimeoutException` thrown by `get` instead, requires a few lines of code, on the other hand, you’re saving the same number of lines by not needing try/catch in the Callable when using `submit`. It’s quite simple. When you want cancelation, you have to use a tool that supports cancelation. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @Holger, I think there was a misunderstanding here. I was merely stating there are 2 objectives: 1. return default value on timeout. 2. On the same timeout, cancel the still background running task. CompletableFuture is very easy doing the first one, keeping it clean, without needing to catch stuff. I understand you saying it doesn't solve the cancelation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `Executor`/`Future` API which supports cancelation with `CompletableFuture`:

```java
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> withInterruptionSupport(Callable<R> c) {
    CompletableFuture<R> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    FutureTask<R> ft = new FutureTask<R>(c) {
        @Override
        protected void set(R v) {
            super.set(v);
            cf.complete(v);
        }
        @Override
        protected void setException(Throwable t) {
            super.setException(t);
            cf.completeExceptionally(t);
        }
    };
    cf.defaultExecutor().execute(ft);
    cf.whenComplete((x,y) -> ft.cancel(true));
    return cf;
}
```

Since support for interruption in the actual function typically implies dealing with `InterruptedException`, it’s convenient to use `Callable` instead of `Supplier`, so it is allowed to throw this exception.

The `Future` which supports cancelation with interruption is unconditionally canceled whenever the `CompletableFuture` completes, which works without problems as whenever the completion stems from the task itself, the future is already completed and the subsequent cancelation will be ignored.

This means, we do not need to distinguish between the different possibilities of completion here. Not only does `completeOnTimeout` work, you can also invoke `cancel(…)` on the `CompletableFuture` and it will interrupt the evaluation of the `Callable` (the `boolean` argument still is irrelevant though). Even calling `complete` with an alternative result without waiting for a timeout would interrupt the now-obsolete evaluation.

So, the following works:

```java
for(int timeout: new int[] { 5, 15 }) {
    System.out.println("with timeout of " + timeout);
    Integer i = withInterruptionSupport(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("5 Calculated!");
            return 5;
        })
        .completeOnTimeout(42, timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .join();
    System.out.println("got " + i);
}
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

```
with timeout of 5
got 42
with timeout of 15
5 Calculated!
got 5
```

Comment: @holgar, Thanks. Upvoted and marked accepted. Nice trick with the `FutureTask`. I still needed the decorator to make `get` behave like `completeOnTimeout`.