# Single Java 8 Stream<String> from a folder content

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

New to Java 8 and practicing `Streams` and `Lambdas`.

I am trying to create a `Stream<String>` out of a folder files content. This is something that I tried unsuccessfully:

```
Stream<String> lineStream = Files.walk(Paths.get("resources")).flatMap(Files::lines);
```

The compiler yells that I am not catching an `IOException` even if I have a throws clause. Can anyone explain this to me?

I managed to print all the files that I am interested in with the following:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("resources"))
    .map(Path::toFile)
    .filter(File::isFile)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

How do I get a `Stream<String>` with each `String` being a line of the files printed by the code above?

Comment: See also this question: [Mandatory checked exceptions handling in lambda expressions for standard Java 8 functional interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039995).

Comment: DO NOT CLOSE IT! Besides the lambda expression throwing a checked exception, is this the best way to concatenate streams from multiple files? Is there a more concise way? What if some files are folders?

Comment: As it stands the question is mostly about dealing with `IOException`, which seems well covered by the other questions and answers. If you have additional questions, you can edit this one to be more specific, or just ask a different question.

Comment: @Gevorg: yes, `flatMap` is a proper way of concatenating streams. To pre-filter the stream of `Path`s, you should get to know about [`Files::isRegularFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-)

Comment: `List<String> rowList = paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .flatMap(a -> { try { return Files.lines(a); }
                    catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e);}})
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());`