# Java8 lambda predicate exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

I have the follow lambda expression:

```
public mylambdafunction(){
Optional<MyClass> optional = Arrays.stream(myClassesValues).filter(x ->
   new String(x.bytesArray,"UTF-16LE").equalsIgnoreCase(comparationString)).findFirst();
}
```

Well, the method   `new String(x.bytesArray,” UTF-16LE”)` raise the Exception `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

I’d like to raise the exception to the main function `mylambdafunction()`, somethings like:

```
public mylambdafunction() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{ 
....
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You may want to read this other question [Checked Exceptions in Lambda Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14039995/697630). It has a good set of answers, most likely you will find yours there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to potentially modifying a functional interface method, since you are using a well known character set, is to use [the overloaded `String` constructor which accepts a `byte[]` and a `Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-), but which doesn't throw `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16LE) as the `Charset` argument.

---

[`Stream#filter(Predicate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) expects a [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) which provides a [`test(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-) method. Since this method does not declare a checked exception which is a supertype of `UnsupportedEncodingException` (and since `UnsupportedEncodingException` is itself checked), then any lambda expression whose body throws such an exception will be incompatible. Similarly, any method reference to a method that declares such an exception will also be incompatible.

Comment: thank you @Sotirios!! This solve my current problem, but I'd like to know if it is possible to raise the exception for the future!

Comment: @J.R. See my most recent edit. The exception is thrown within your lambda body. Unless you `try-catch` it within it, the method must be able to throw it. But throwing it is incompatible with the `Predicate` functional interface.