# Extending Exception/RuntimeException in java?

Tags: java, exception

I have below classes.

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {


}
```

and

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception {


}
```

I am confused as to when the custom exception should extend `RuntimeException` and when it has to extend `Exception`. Could you please explain me is there any disadvantage of extending `RuntimeException` directly?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to choose checked and unchecked exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578/when-to-choose-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> RuntimeException are unchecked while Exception are checked (calling
>   code must handle them).

The custom exception should extends `RuntimeException` if you **want to make it unchecked** else extend it with `Exception`.

With unchecked exceptions calling code method is not required to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of `RuntimeException` that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught.

As the calling method may not handle `RuntimeException``, one needs to be **careful while throwing RuntimeException**.

Runtime exceptions represent problems that are the result of a programming problem, and as such, the API client code cannot reasonably be expected to recover from them or to handle them in any way. Such problems include arithmetic exceptions, such as dividing by zero; pointer exceptions, such as trying to access an object through a null reference; and indexing exceptions, such as attempting to access an array element through an index that is too large or too small.

Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).

**Source/Further Reading:** [Unchecked Exceptions - The Controversy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Comment: quoting from answer by @Batty: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

Comment: One thing that is important to note is that checked exceptions are braking encapsulation. For example, the caller needs to know what type of exception the called is potentially throwing, hence the caller has internal knowledge of the called which is what breaks encapsulation. If you are programming using OOP this might be a problem (I don't really use functional programming or procedural programming so I can't really say how it is in these kind of practices).

Answer (score 19):

If you extend `RuntimeException`, you don't need to declare it in the throws clause (i.e. it's an unchecked exception). If you extend Exception, you do (it's a checked exception).

Some people argue that all exceptions should extend from `RuntimeException`, but if you want to force the user to handle the exception, you should extend `Exception` instead.

Comment: Why do they argue this ? Is it because Checked exceptions can make the code ugly and/or unnecessarily verbose ?

Answer (score 8):

> One case where it is common practice to throw a RuntimeException is when the user calls a method incorrectly. For example, a method can check if one of its arguments is incorrectly null. If an argument is null, the method might throw a NullPointerException, which is an unchecked exception.
>
> Generally speaking, do not throw a RuntimeException or create a subclass of RuntimeException simply because you don't want to be bothered with specifying the exceptions your methods can throw.
>
> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

for more [read this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an application framework and your framework is good to handle the exception when there is an exception notification from your code.  In that case you can use your custom exception class as subclass of RuntimeException.

This will help you from NOT to write the code to handle the exception through out the exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

> RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

If you extend `Exception`, you need to catch where ever you throw your `ValidationException`.