# Exception handling in java for checked and unchecked exception

Tags: exception

If we want to make a checked exception, we can extend the `Exception` class, and for unchecked exceptions we can extend the `RuntimeException` class.

But the `Exception` class is a super for `RuntimeException`, so why can't I make a runtime exception class using the `Exception` class?

[Extending Exception/RunTimeException in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857008/extending-exception-runtimeexception-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a feature of the language. Keep in mind that there are other [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) classes, most notably [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) and its children, none of which you are required to check for. [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) are just markers in the inheritance tree that the compiler uses to check if a `Throwable` needs to be checked or not, pretty much because the authors of the language decided that those would be the names of those markers.

Comment: Thanks Mad Physicist for the reply.

Comment: @AshwaniPundir. If the reply helps you, you can select it by clicking the check mark on the left. That will mark the question as answered.