# Is there any custom exception already in library which we can use where ever we want it to throw with custom message?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I want to throw a run-time exception from a method which will be caught in another class, which in turn throws a further specific custom exception or does some operation.

```
    def checkExtension(String fileName,file) {

    String [] arr= Holders.config.bdmserver.defaultfile_ext
       for (int i=0; i < arr.length-1;i++) {
        println("file extension=" + fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 3))
        if (arr[i].equals(fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4))) {
            println("in if becoz its either .zip or .exe")
            // throw run-time exception 
        }
    }

    def fileSize = (file.getSize())/12000
    if (fileSize > 5 ){
       // throw run-time exception 
    }


}
```

in different class

```
catch (run-time exception ex){
                 throw new ApplicationException(BdmsException, messageSource.getMessage("file.upload.failureExtension.message", "Error!! you can not upload a file with this extension", Locale.getDefault()), ex)
        }
```

How can I do it without creating a new custom exception class?

Comment: What is your aversion to just creating a custom exception in your project?

Comment: This is not Java. Scala perhaps? 'I want to throw a run-time exception from a method which will be caught in another class, which in turn throws a further specific custom exception': so why does it have to be a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: first of all, its a groovy code. If you see the logic, its actually uploading a file and I want to throw an exception if someone try's to upload .exe file.

Comment: I can always create a custom exception but its just tedious job in this case as I have to follow the organization standards to create custom exception in jar by following other standards for that particular jar.

Comment: use IllegalArgumentException with proper message, though using a custom business exception is better

Comment: that's so nice of you Jon. Thank you. I will re-post that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own exception type, with the message that you need, inheriting from `RuntimeException`. And in your code just put: `throw new MyRuntimeException("Put message here");`. This way you can be sure you are handling your own exception.

But, if you are not interested in handling this particular exception just use `throw new RuntimeException("Put message here");`

[Remember that Runtime Exceptions are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19857096/5627387)

Comment: explicitedly says he does not want new exception type yet you suggest for him to make custom exception?

Comment: I'm countering the downvote on the grounds that creating a custom exception may actually be the most prudent thing to do here.

Comment: while that is true, it does not answer the question

Comment: throw new RuntimeException("Put message here"); worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not want to create a custom exception yourself?

Anyhow, I'd go for the `UnsupportedOperationException` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way without new type is to create normal exception (`Exception` or `RuntimeException`, both support string message), passing some specific message of your choice and then in later code checking against `Exception` or `RuntimeException` and matching your message.

```
try {
    throw new Exception("my specific string message");
catch (Exception e) {
    if ("my specific string message".equals(e.getMessage()) {
        // your code
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

potential drawback is that now you have to declare exception if it is `Exception`. Solutions are to use `RuntimeException` or `Unsafe.throwException()`

Comment: I tried above solution, it doesn't throw an exception if you are calling the method from other class. In-fact e.getMessage() is null.

Comment: message is something you should set yourself as an identifier tag

Comment: Obviously, I did set a message but its still null.