# Separating of Data and Function in Java

Tags: javascript, java, json

I want to initialize a deck of individual cards in Java. This is my approach so far:

```
public ArrayList<Card> initDeck() {
    ArrayList<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<Card>(24);

    cardDeck.add(new Card("Emperor Augustus", 20.1, 40, 4.1, 300000, POWER_AND_INFLUENCE.VERY_HIGH));
    cardDeck.add(new Card("Jeff Bezos", 96, 22, 59.7, 268000, POWER_AND_INFLUENCE.HIGH));
    cardDeck.add(new Card("Bill Gates", 83.7, 41, 73, 112388, POWER_AND_INFLUENCE.MEDIUM));

    return cardDeck;
}
```

This is a lot of repetition IMO. Also I want to separate the data from function.

Is it possible to export the elements I want to add into cardDeck, i.e. `new Card(...)` into a separate file?

In JavaScript you would make it for example like this:

JSON-File:

```
{
    data: [{
        name: "asdf",
        economy: 123,
        yearsInPower: 4
    }, {
        name: "bsdf",
        economy: 3,
        yearsInPower: 10
    }, {
        name: "csdf",
        economy: 43,
        yearsInPower: 5
    }]
}
```

JS-File:

```
const cards = require("./cards.json").data;

function initDeck(cards) {
    const cardDeck = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cardDeck.push(cards[i]);
    }
    return cardDeck;
}

let cardDeck = initDeck(cards);
```

I've looked into other implementation of the initialization of cards in Java. But all the examples assumes a logical order of the cards, e.g. 2,3,4...Jack, Queen, King, Ace. But in my example the cards don't follow any logical order.

Comment: There are packages available for Java to read name/value data in various formats: JSON, YAML, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can separate data from code (like loading from files, database, etc..).

If you wanted to load data from JSON file, then you can use [Jackson library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.3) to read the data from JSON and convert to Java objects (deserialization) as shown below:

```
public List<Card> initDeck() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Card[] staff = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\cards.json"), Card[].class);
    List<Card> cardDeck = Arrays.asList(staff);
    return cardDeck;
}
```

Also, as a side note, remember that it is always a best practice to code for interfaces `List<Card>` as `return` types (shown above) rather than concrete classes like `ArrayList, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) on the same subject.

Comment: Is `throws Exception` the same as a `try-catch`-block in the function body?

Comment: Either you need to `catch` the Exception inside the function or `throw` from the function so that the caller needs to handle it

Comment: Does it make sense to add a `throw` to every method you write?

Comment: You don't write throw for each method, only when there are checked exceptions, you need to specify in your method signature, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578/when-to-choose-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions?rq=1