# Why i need to handle Complie Time exception if they are going to be caught in the run time

Tags: java, exception

I have to handle file not found exception. But the file availablity will be known only during run time. Why i should handle it. also Null pointer or run time exception occurs during run time, that we do not handle?

Comment: Are you going to go to your customer's house and edit the code to add exception handling when runtime happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to choose checked and unchecked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578/when-to-choose-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions)

Comment: My Question was why does compiler prompts to handle File not found if the real exception happens at run time and not for Null pointer

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of checked exceptions is to force you, the programmer, to intentionally either:

1. Handle the exception, or
2. Declare you expect the caller to handle it

This can go all the way up to `main` or whatever your program's main entry point is. So if you *really* want the entire program to crash and burn because the file couldn't be found, you could declare all of the methods leading up to that code as throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

More likely, you want to provide a better UX than that, by handling the error and showing the user a nicer error message.

In contrast, *unchecked* exceptions are for

- Programming errors (you tried to access a property on `null`, index past the end of an array, etc.), and
- Runtime errors the code won't be able to handle nicely, such as out-of-memory conditions.

You don't have to declare or handle those, because by the time the code is shipped to a user, testing should have gotten rid of all of the first type (programming errors), and there's nothing your code can do about the second type.